# Seaborn draw line on mean data points when plotting (not a linear line)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to make my plots in Python better. I have created a Seaborn graph with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(times=times, wait=wait, triage=triage))

flatui = ["#3498db", "#2ecc71", "#3498db"]
sns.set_palette(flatui)
sns.lmplot('times', 'wait', data=df, fit_reg=False, height=10, x_estimator=np.mean, truncate=True)
plt.ylabel("Waiting time",fontsize='20')
plt.xlabel("Time at day (0-23)",fontsize='20')
```

Using `x_estimator = np.mean` 2200+ data points are drawn. With the `np.mean`, only 24 points are drawn as x axis is time at day (0-23).

When using the `np.mean` I also want to draw a line through every point, is there a way to do this?

The plot the code produces looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can additionally just plot the mean values using `matplotlib`. Assuming you have the 24 mean values in a list/array called `mean_val`, you can do the following. It will simply put a line connecting the mean values (circles).

```
ax = sns.lmplot('times', 'wait', data=df, fit_reg=False, height=10, x_estimator=np.mean, truncate=True)
ax.plot(range(len(mean_val)), mean_val, '-b')
```

Comment: So its not possible when using the lmplot?

Comment: There might be but I am not sure since the documentation is really not so clear. I would hence use a workaround solution like in my answer.

Comment: @Ray: I dont have your data. Can you try my answer and tell if it works

Comment: Can you do something so the lines are not linear, but curvy?, right now the are straigt from point to point.

Comment: Matplotlib connects the line linearly unlike Excel sheet plots which curves the lines. For that you would need some sort of Spline interpolation

Comment: im not downvoting.

Comment: For your answer to curve, you can try `from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`, `spline = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(range(len(mean_val)), mean_val)` and then `plt.plot((range(len(mean_val)), spline((range(len(mean_val))))`